# What does "Live" mean in Linux kernel mod list?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

What does "Live" mean next to loaded kernel modules?

```
root@zcu106:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
al5e                   16384  0
al5d                   16384  0
allegro                36864  2 al5e,al5d
xilinx_hdmi_tx        110592  0
mali                  241664  0
xilinx_hdmi_rx         86016  0
si5324                 20480  2
xlnx_vcu               20480  1 allegro
dp159                  16384  1
xilinx_vphy           245760  8 xilinx_hdmi_tx,xilinx_hdmi_rx
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0

root@zcu106:~# more /proc/modules 
al5e 16384 0 - Live 0xffffff8000c74000 (O)
al5d 16384 0 - Live 0xffffff8000c6b000 (O)
allegro 36864 2 al5e,al5d, Live 0xffffff8000c4b000 (O)
xilinx_hdmi_tx 110592 0 - Live 0xffffff8000c25000 (O)
mali 241664 0 - Live 0xffffff8000b80000 (O)
xilinx_hdmi_rx 86016 0 - Live 0xffffff8000b57000 (O)
si5324 20480 2 - Live 0xffffff8000b4d000 (O)
xlnx_vcu 20480 1 allegro, Live 0xffffff8000b44000
dp159 16384 1 - Live 0xffffff8000aea000 (O)
xilinx_vphy 245760 8 xilinx_hdmi_tx,xilinx_hdmi_rx, Live 0xffffff8000a98000 (O)
uio_pdrv_genirq 16384 0 - Live 0xffffff8000a90000
```

Comment: references: [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Reference Guide /proc/modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-modules.html), [Module marked (F) in /proc/modules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152507/module-marked-f-in-proc-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells what load state the module is in: Live, Loading, or Unloading are the only possible values.  Live means they have been loaded properly in the system and they are up and running